# merge socket.io and express.js sessions

Tags: javascript, session, express, socket.io

I want to merge express.js and socket.io sessions together. Below is my code (socket.io part)

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
io.set('log level', 1);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('client connected');
client.send(client.id);//send client id to client itself
socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log(socket.id + ' connected');
});
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log(socket.id + ' disconnected');
});
});
```

My express.js Session settings:

```
app.configure(function() {
  //app.use(express.logger());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({store: MemStore({
    reapInterval: 60000 * 10
  }), secret:'foobar', key: 'express.sid'
}));
```

My main problem is in my terminal when user travels from one url to another, the session id changes also: But I don't want it to be changed.

```
info  - socket.io started
client connected
client connected
4Z0bYHzfWCEFzbbe4WUK disconnected
e_uSvxhSLbLAC9-F4WUL disconnected
client connected
bKDy90gsrWWTRJDD4WUM disconnected
client connected
RJ5qqCL2wfmXbd7U4WUN disconnected
client connected
wjN5Sqx4rucRtWL_4WUO disconnected
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are outputting the socket ID, not the session ID from express.js.

You must use the `authorization` event, its first parameter is an object which has an entry called `sessionID`. That value shouldn't change between page reloads, as it is stored in a cookie (or redis database or whatever).

Here is a good article explaining how it works: http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/ , but it's a little outdated. The basic principle stays the same, but a few details have changed. For example the way he creates the server doesn't work anymore, and the connect developers have removed `parseCookie()`. Users are [not happy](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/588) with that decision, however the workaround is this easy-to-remember line of code:

```
connect.utils.parseSignedCookies(cookie.parse(decodeURIComponent(data.headers.cookie)), secret);
```

As I said, the article mentioned above should give you all the basics you need, if you want to see a working implementation, take a look at this: https://github.com/vortec/lolbr/blob/master/lib/lolbr.js

Inside the `authorization` event handler, you can modify the `data` object and access it later it using `socket.handshake`, in your case: `socket.handshake.sessionID`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Alex if you clone ``lolbr``, make sure you have ``express`` installed below it. Just clone, then ``cd`` into it and type ``npm install``. That should work.

Comment: So, parseSignedCookies are not available right now. How do you suggest to re-write the code? I'm not familiar with Cookies in socket.io, but I've found "var cookies = cookie.parse('foo=bar; cat=meow; dog=ruff');" example. How should I implement it to this example?

Comment: Why is ``parseSignedCookies`` not available in the first place? Do you mean that it's not available in your node.js environment?

Comment: Try to replace ``connect = require('express/node_modules/connect')`` with ``connect = require('connect')``.

Comment: Now that I am thinking about this.... why not just set the store for the cookies and the store for the socket to the same store?